# How to send pull request to someone I only have his email

Tags: github, pull-request

As part of a job interview I was asked to write some code and send the result as a pull request.

I opened a new repository for my project, and now that I'm done, I wanted to send a pull request to review my code and commits.

The problem is - I didn't receive any branch/repository/instruction on how to send him this pull request.

What should I do now? Do I branch my own code and add him as contributer?

How can I send him my current repository (with all the commits and notes) as a pull request when all I have is his email.
What am I missing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can make public pull requests on your own repository as well, and send the link to that pull request by email. If your repository is public they can clone it if they want, but just to see your changes they don't need to clone anything.

Answer (score 0):

You’re correct. In order to make a pull request you need another
repository to make a pull request *against*.

But for style/alienation points you can do this:

- Create public repository
- `git request-pull <root commit> <url> <branch>`
- Copy the output into your email (plaintext)

This will effectively ask them to pull your whole repository.